# PHP script on Windows Server (IIS)

Tags: php, performance, iis, windows-server

We've currently moved our website to a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. 
It's running IIS7 and on that PHP5.4

Everything seems to work properly, but there's a strange behaviour I can't seem to fix.
When I load a site, and look at the way it's loaded (The 'Net' tab in Firebug or something), the timeline shows me that everything is loaded very quick, but when the 'main page' (the initial GET request) is loaded, it seems like the server is just 'waiting/idle' for 2 seconds.

http://imageshack.us/f/819/ne5n.jpg/

Does anyone knows what happens?

Comment: You can simply check the "timeline" tab to see what happens http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/8223/rgww.png

Comment: Forgot to add that, I did look at that, everything is very fast, except the 'waiting' part, which takes 2s.

Comment: Seems your code running slow, just check your code running at the server side.

Comment: @Drazzi Well, the code is running perfectly fine on other machines. So it doesn't seem to be the code